# JavaFX application is slow outside Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, javafx

So I have just packaged my JavaFX 8 application using the zenjava maven plugin in eclipse. Unfortunately my application performance outside of Eclipse is abysmal. The application connects to an online database that I have set up and allows users to query items in the database. When I run the application in Eclipse it takes 3-6 seconds to start up, but when I am running commands in it the response is almost instant. Now that I have my jar packaged and running on my terminal it takes at least 10 seconds to start up and responses are frustratingly slow.

I have seen that the option -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true has helped many people overcome what seems a similar problem, but when I run

```
java -jar -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true application.jar arg
```

it is not any faster than it was originally. Most of the other ways I have seen to deal with this is done in Netbeans, which I do not use. Curious if anyone has dealt with this in Eclipse and can provide any insight? Thanks!

Comment: What does your logging say? Does it indeed indicate that the problem is the network connection?

Comment: My logs don't indicate any issues at all. Everything technically works. My app starts a connection to a database at start up, which is successfully created. My queries all also succeed and eventually (1+min) return and the application displays the results. The only problem is the lag. I think this definitely has to do with some type of network issue. All the UI changes in the application that do not have something go across the network are just as quick as in Eclipse. All changes that do have something go across the network take forever.

Comment: I mean the time differences in the methods. Either check the time in the log to definitely determine the code position of the problem or create yourself a stopwatch class with which you can measure time. Besides of that, what do you mean with (1+min)? That your queries take longer than 1 min? Is there a huge amount of data? Because if so, I'd also check the amount of memory that you give your java application. It may differ between the DevEnv and the standalone jar.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe eclipse is keeping a database connection open for you.

Comment: Being Javafx, You may also want to throw some gc args in as well..
I had a case where the gc was hanging things up and not doing it's job properly.

Comment: Can you check the flags that eclipse is using then it runs your application?